# Retrieving a product's sold quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've written a view to retrieve each product's sold quantity and four week sales average by `Branch`/`Route`/`Customer`.

**Introduction to Dataset**

- It might be easiest to start with the innermost query (commented as `B: SalesByWeek grouped by Branch.`) since it's the base and the outer queries are the same query grouped by Route and Customer instead.
- `Branch`es contain one or many `Route`s.
- `Route`s contain one or many `Customer`s.
- `SAP_VisitPlan` is an effectivity table. It defines which customers are on which routes and which routes are on which branches.
- `vw_SalesByWeek` is two cache tables unioned to obtain all customer sales week totals.

**The View**

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_SalesByWeekSummary]
AS
    SELECT VP.Branch
         , VP.ROUTE AS Route
         , VP.SAPCustomerID
         , S.SalesType
         , S.CustomerID
         , S.ProductID
         , S.Date
         , SUM(Quantity) AS CustomerQuantity
         , SUM(FourWeekSalesAvg) AS CustomerFourWeekSalesAvg
         , R.RouteQuantity
         , R.RouteFourWeekSalesAvg
         , R.BranchQuantity
         , R.BranchFourWeekSalesAvg
    FROM vw_SalesByWeek AS S WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN SAP_VisitPlan AS VP WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON VP.CustomerID = S.CustomerID
       AND VP.DateFrom <= S.Date
       AND VP.DateTo >= S.Date
    INNER JOIN (

        -- R: SalesByWeek grouped by Route.
        SELECT VP.Branch
             , VP.ROUTE AS Route
             , S.ProductID
             , S.Date
             , SUM(Quantity) AS RouteQuantity
             , SUM(FourWeekSalesAvg) AS RouteFourWeekSalesAvg
             , B.BranchQuantity
             , B.BranchFourWeekSalesAvg
        FROM vw_SalesByWeek AS S WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN SAP_VisitPlan AS VP WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON VP.CustomerID = S.CustomerID
           AND VP.DateFrom <= S.Date
           AND VP.DateTo >= S.Date
        INNER JOIN (

            -- B: SalesByWeek grouped by Branch.
            SELECT VP.Branch
                 , ProductID
                 , Date
                 , SUM(Quantity) AS BranchQuantity
                 , SUM(FourWeekSalesAvg) AS BranchFourWeekSalesAvg
            FROM vw_SalesByWeek AS S WITH (NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN SAP_VisitPlan AS VP WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON VP.CustomerID = S.CustomerID
               AND VP.DateFrom <= S.Date
               AND VP.DateTo >= S.Date
            GROUP BY VP.Branch, ProductID, Date

        ) AS B
            ON B.Branch = VP.Branch
           AND B.ProductID = S.ProductID
           AND B.Date = S.Date
        GROUP BY VP.Branch, VP.ROUTE, S.ProductID, S.Date, B.BranchQuantity, B.BranchFourWeekSalesAvg

    ) AS R
        ON R.Branch = VP.Branch
       AND R.Route = VP.ROUTE
       AND R.ProductID = S.ProductID
       AND R.Date = S.Date
    GROUP BY VP.Branch, VP.ROUTE, VP.SAPCustomerID, S.SalesType, S.CustomerID, S.ProductID, S.Date, R.BranchQuantity, R.BranchFourWeekSalesAvg, R.RouteQuantity, R.RouteFourWeekSalesAvg
GO
```

**vw_SalesByWeek Query**

```
SELECT 'Conv' AS [SalesType]
     , [CustomerID]
     , [ProductID]
     , [WkStartDate] AS [Date]
     , [SoldQuantity] AS [Quantity]
     , [Route]
     , [FourWeekSalesAvg]
     , [NumberOfPriorSalesWeeks]
FROM Cache_ConvSalesByWeek WITH (NOLOCK)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Scan' AS [SalesType]
     , [CustomerID]
     , [ProductID]
     , [WkStartDate]
     , [SoldQuantity]
     , [Route]
     , [FourWeekSalesAvg]
     , [NumberOfPriorSalesWeeks]
FROM Cache_ScanSalesByWeek WITH (NOLOCK)
```

**Usage Query**

```
SELECT Branch
     , Route
     , SAPCustomerID
     , SalesType
     , CustomerID
     , ProductID
     , Date
     , CustomerQuantity
     , CustomerFourWeekSalesAvg
     , RouteQuantity
     , RouteFourWeekSalesAvg
     , BranchQuantity
     , BranchFourWeekSalesAvg
FROM vw_SalesByWeekSummary
WHERE Route = '0600'
  AND Date = '08/06/2018'
```

**Concerns**

- My concern is readability. I don't like that this query is basically the same query 3 times with different groupings for the sums.
- I originally wrote this as three views that built on one-another. That is, one for the branch sums, one for the route sums, and one for the customer sums where each subsequent view used the prior. My co-workers did not like this as they fear a dependency-hell style scenario.
- I have two other queries similar to this structurally, so any improvements that could be made will be incredibly helpful and appreciated.

**Question**

Is there a way to write this query in a more concise or conceptually simplistic way, possibly with less repetition?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Comment: Can you post the source SQL for vw_SalesByWeek?

Comment: I've added it to the question. vw_SalesByWeek is just a simple union between two tables that have sales for two different types of customers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would test using the [OVER clause with aggregate functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). This may speed up your results and make it a bit more readable. You may also want to check out the [ranking functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Here is an example of your view I updated to use the `OVER` clause.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_SalesByWeekSummary]
AS

    SELECT 
           VP.[Branch]
         , [Route] = VP.[ROUTE]
         , VP.[SAPCustomerID]
         , S.[SalesType]
         , S.[CustomerID]
         , S.[ProductID]
         , S.[Date]
         , [CustomerQuantity] = SUM(S.[Quantity]) OVER (PARTITION BY VP.[Branch], VP.[ROUTE], VP.[SAPCustomerID], S.[SalesType], S.[CustomerID], S.[ProductID], S.[Date])
         , [CustomerFourWeekSalesAvg] = SUM(S.[FourWeekSalesAvg]) OVER (PARTITION BY VP.[Branch], VP.[ROUTE], VP.[SAPCustomerID], S.[SalesType], S.[CustomerID], S.[ProductID], S.[Date])
         , [RouteQuantity] = SUM(S.[Quantity]) OVER (PARTITION BY VP.[Branch], VP.[ROUTE], S.[ProductID], S.[Date]) 
         , [RouteFourWeekSalesAvg] = SUM(S.[FourWeekSalesAvg]) OVER (PARTITION BY VP.[Branch], VP.[ROUTE], S.[ProductID], S.[Date]) 
         , [BranchQuantity] = SUM(S.[Quantity]) OVER (PARTITION BY VP.[Branch], S.[ProductID], S.[Date]) 
         , [BranchFourWeekSalesAvg] = SUM(S.[FourWeekSalesAvg]) OVER (PARTITION BY VP.[Branch], S.[ProductID], S.[Date]) 
    FROM 
        vw_SalesByWeek AS S WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN SAP_VisitPlan AS VP WITH (NOLOCK) ON VP.[CustomerID] = S.[CustomerID] AND VP.[DateFrom] <= S.[Date] AND VP.[DateTo] >= S.[Date] 


GO
```

I use `Display Estimated Execution Plan` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in [Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) to check the performance of the query by pasting both SQL statements in a query window.

Here's an example.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The `PARTITION BY`  lines are throwing an error complaining about not being in the `GROUP BY`. Trying to figure this out on my own, but it's going to take a while since I've never used the `OVER` clause.

Comment: I removed the `GROUP BY` and added an `OVER` clause to the Customer quantity and FourWeekSalesAvg and it seems to be working now. Going to experiment around with this a bit.

Comment: Cool, that's exactly what I was thinking

Comment: @aduguid What program do you use to test these queries with?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Comment: It's a free download https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I didn't even know about the OVER clause, I've been missing out. Not only is my query more concise but it's performing on average 13x faster. I had two other similar queries to so that's a great deal of help to me. Thanks!

Comment: I just learned about them a few months ago. BTW, if you haven't already started using CTEs. (Common Table Expressions), they're pretty cool too.

Comment: I've only ever used those for a really bad recursive CTE once. Not entirely sure why I would use them, I guess I'll do some research then :)

Comment: I find using CTEs are a bit better to read than correlated sub queries.

Comment: @Shelby115 One of the advantages of a CTE is it's stored on the DB system itself. You no longer have to send it over every time. Which saves a whole lot of time if you run a couple hundred thousand queries right after each other.

Comment: @Mast Aren't Stored Procedures stored on the DB System itself? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: No, you're right, I tend to mix them up. I was talking about stored procedures, my bad... A CTE is quite useful too though, especially if you need a temporary view with a couple of complex queries, like it appears you're doing. [This page](http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/sql-server-what-is-common-table-expression-cte/) gives a couple of good examples why a CTE is useful in your case.